# Ignore NerdTree buffer when manipulating splits

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

When dealing with multiple splits, the split management commands are very useful: `<C-W> R/r` or `<C-w><S-h>`, for instance.

The issue I have is that when I have a NedTree buffer opened as a split, a command like `<C-W>R` or `<C-W><S-h>` will also move the NerdTree split which is obviously not the desired result.

I tried re-mapping these commands by including `:NERTreeToggle<CR>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>` but that doesn't work and is pretty clunky anyway.

Is there a way to "lock" the NerdTree split either on the left or the right side and have it be ignored by split manipulation commands ?

Comment: No, all windows are equal before the law.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32400443) is relevant to your situation, even though it was posted in response to a completely different question.

Comment: +1 on that vimcasts video. Again, not an answer, but after getting frustrated with NERDTree, watching that video, and installing Tim Pope's [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) plugin, I'm glad I broke myself of NERDTree's grip on my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just closed Nerdtree before moving your splits thereby avoiding any of the ensuing issues:

```
nnoremap <C-W> :NERDTreeClose<CR><C-W>
```

Once you're done juggling your split screens, reopen Nerdtree. If you need to be *fancy*, combine closing, rotating splits and reopening Nerdtree in one mapping, something like:

```
nnoremap <C-W>r :NERDTreeClose<CR><C-W>r<bar>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```